# Spring @PathVariable without ending slash (String with IP address)

Tags: java, json, spring, url, path-variables

this is part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/json/getPCs/{serverAddress}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<PC> getPCForServerJSON(@PathVariable String serverAddress) {
    logger.info("Server address: " + serverAddress);
    return PCManager.findByServer(serverManager.findByAddress(serverAddress));
}
```

In browser I visit URL `http://localhost:8080/test/pc/json/getPCs/192.168.200.1`

in log I see:

```
INFO : net.example.test.PCController - Server addres: 192.168.200
```

if I go to URL `http://localhost:8080/test/pc/json/getPCs/192.168.200.1/` with slash on end it is ok:

```
INFO : net.example.test.PCController - Server addres: 192.168.200.1
```

Why? I would like to use url without ending slash.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` to create `PatternsRequestCondition` instances (which match your path segments) without matching suffixes.

In a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`, override the following

```
@Override
public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    return mapping;
}
```

That configuration parameter is enabled (`true`) by default

> If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to "/users.*".

So your path segment

```
{serverAddress}
```

is actually matching

```
{serverAddress}[.].*
//              ^ literally a dot
```

So given the value

```
192.168.200.1
```

it captures only

```
192.168.200
```

Disabling it will give you the behavior you want.